# IdentityServer4 without redirects

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I'm implementing IdentityServer4 as my authentication service.

The client that will use this is an Angular app. From all the examples I've seen, the client is redirected to a page hosted on the identity server which is returned back to the client afterwards.

For user experience, I would like to keep the user on my page the whole time. So this leads to a couple of questions:

1. Can the identity server UI be displayed in a DIV or an iframe within a site? I'm guessing that iframe is a bit frowned upon?
2. If the above is not possible, is it possible to host the login UI on the client app, not the identity server?

I suppose it's more of a question for the UX group, but I would have thought that keeping the user within the site would lead to a better user experience instead of redirecting them completely?

Answer (score 11):

The UX question depends on a number of things, and UX has to be tempered by security considerations.

If you completely own the client, and the identity server, you could use the `ResourceOwnerPasswordFlow` which doesn't involve redirects and allows your client to take the username/password and obtain an access token using them.

This kind of flow though is not recommended if you don't own the client, and/or don't trust it with the credentials. Imagine the situation where a website delegates their login process to something like Google/Facebook ... as the owner of the identity (Google/Facebook) you *really* wouldn't want your customers entering their password into some random website. Instead you would use the redirect flows to present a familiar and trusted URL that the customer would be happier to enter their details into.

So the question of redirects isn't a simple 'it gives bad UX', because in many cases it is a better UX to involve redirects if that brings with it an enhanced sense of security.

Comment: This and RO wont give you SSO if you have multiple client applications.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen IdentityServer4 projects configured to work with SPAs, although I don't have all the details here off the top of my head.

Check out this piece of the [documentation](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_javascript_client.html):

> Defining browser-based JavaScript client (e.g. SPA) for user
> authentication and delegated access and API This client uses the so
> called implicit flow to request an identity and access token from
> JavaScript:
>
> ```
> var jsClient = new Client {
> ClientId = "js",
> ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
> ClientUri = "http://identityserver.io",
>
> AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
> AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
>
> RedirectUris =           { "http://localhost:7017/index.html" },
> PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:7017/index.html" },
> AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://localhost:7017" },
>
> AllowedScopes =
> {
>     IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
>     IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
>     IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
>
>     "api1", "api2.read_only"
> } };
> ```

You can see all the redirects go back to the same URL. Presumably, your routing would take over from there.